Calculating the speed of an ejected electron
I'm working on some physics exercises and came across this one. Sadly, there is no solution provided, so I was wondering if at least my line of reasoning is correct.
 Radiation with a wavelength of 165 nm strikes a metal and an electron is ejected with a speed of 1.24Mm/s. Calculate the speed of electrons ejected if the radiation was 265nm
So, I went about it like this:

Calculate the kinetic energy of the photon going in:

$E_k = h\frac{c}{\lambda}$, so $6.626*10^{-34}*\frac{2.998*10^{8}}{1.65*10^{-7}} = 1.2039 * 10^{-18} J$

Calculate the kinetic energy of the electron going out:
$E_k = \frac{1}{2}(9.1094*10^{-31})*(1.24*10^6)^2 = 7 *10^{-19} J$

The difference in the energies, must be the amount of energy needed to do work on the metal. Subtract those and use it to calculate the energy that's available for the electron that shoots out if the metal with the radiation of the higher wavelength.


$E_{work} = 1.2039 * 10^{-18} - 7 *10^{-19} = 5.0357*10^{-19}$
Then we calculate the energy of the photon at 265, like in step 1.
Use the outcome of that minus the energy taken for the work, and use that energy as the kinetic energy of the electron that comes out to calculate its speed
Is step 3 the right way to think about this?

Photon going out?

Electron* going out.

This seems to be a theorist's idealization. What really happens in such an experiment is a lot more complicated and random.

The idealized world of someone who's just barely scratching the surface and trying to understand some basic principles

It's basically right for the maximum energies of the ejected electrons. But, in reality, there are mechanisms that rob the photoelectron of energy before ejection. Thus, in an experiment, you'll see a distribution of electron energies from 0 to the maximum.

Thanks, I don't think those details are a concern at this point, but I will keep it in mind when we advance into the materials
